# Different Dany compile outputs for witness clause when compiled using VSC and the standalone compiler

Tags: dafny

I have this simple code which uses witness clause to initialize a default value for the variable n. When compiled using the standalone version of the compiler I get the expected behavior which is the default witness value.

```
type Pos = i: int | i > 0 witness 1
method Main()
{ 
  var n:Pos;
  print "n:",n;
}
```

The Dafny reference manual states this clearly,

> The declaration of a subset type permits an optional witness clause, to declare default values that the compiler can use to initialize variables of the subset type, or to assert the non-emptiness of the subset type.

However, when I compile the same code using the Visual Studio Code, it got stuck at trying to initialize the variable. It complains with the error message,

> "variable 'n', which is subject to definite-assignment rules, might be uninitialized here"

The terminal output is,

> PS C:\Users\Acer.vscode\extensions\dafny-lang.ide-vscode-3.0.9\out\resources\4.0.0\github\dafny> & "C:\Program Files\dotnet6\dotnet.exe" c:\Users\Acer.vscode\extensions\dafny-lang.ide-vscode-3.0.9\out\resources\4.0.0\github\dafny\Dafny.dll run "e:\witness\witnessexample.dfy"

> e:/witness/witnessexample.dfy(12,14): Error: variable 'n', which is subject to definite-assignment rules, might be uninitialized here

Currently, the standalone version of Dafny is 4.0.0.50303.

Is is possible that the version of Dafny.dll is not compatible with Dafny.exe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation

The issue you're facing is that Dafny's definite-assignment rules changed in Dafny 4.0, see https://github.com/dafny-lang/ide-vscode/wiki/Quick-migration-guide-from-Dafny-3.X-to-Dafny-4.0#definite-assignment.

When you use VS Code, you get the new, stricter rule. You also get this stricter rule in the new command-line interface (this CLI uses verbs like `verify` and `run`). For example, you'll see the same error if you try

```
dafny verify test.dfy
```

However, the legacy CLI (that is, without using such a verb) still uses the old, relaxed definite-assignment rule. Therefore, the command

```
dafny test.dfy
```

does not give any error.

### What to do

Usually, the response to a definite-assignment error is to manually provide an initialization of the variable. However, if you're okay with Dafny picking an arbitrary value for the local variable `n`, you can use the assignment `n := *;`. Because `Pos` is an auto-init type (that is, the compiler knows the type is nonempty and knows of some way to initialize the variable), the `n := *;` assignment will satisfy the definite-assignment rule.

### More info

If you want the old rule (which I don't recommend, unless you have some legacy Dafny code that you're trying to migrate into Dafny 4.0), then you can use the `--relax-definite-assignment` option with the new CLI. If you want the strict rule with the legacy CLI, use the `/definiteAssignment:4` option.

A final note. The sentence you're quoting from the reference manual is confusing. (I will file a bug to get it fixed.) The `witness` clause does *not* declare a default value. It only declares an *example* value, which is used as a proof that there exists a value that the compiler can use to initialize variables. The language does *not* guarantee that you'll get that exact value. Case in point: the verifier will flag the second assertion in the following code as an error, because there's no guarantee that the value picked will be `1`.

```
type Pos = i: int | i > 0 witness 1

method Main()
{ 
  var n: Pos := *;
  assert n > 0; // yes, the verifier proves this assertion
  assert n == 1; // error: variable n can be any value of type Pos, not necessarily 1
  print "n:", n;
}
```

Comment: Documentation bug submitted as https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/issues/3834.

Comment: That makes it clear. I guess "can use" is the source of confusion. Probably, "compiler may possibly but not necessarily use to initialize" is more like it.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the paragraph you quoted probably only applies to the verification context and not the compiled context. Meaning that if you are trying to verify various properties the compiler will reach for that default value to initialize in the verification of statements. The verification compiler does test values to see if properties are valid.

However, if you add an assert to the function.

```
method Main()
{ 
  var n:Pos;
  assert n == 1;
  print "n:",n;
}
```

You can see that Dafny does not assume 1 to be the default value of the variable.

Comment: Your comment doesn't answer the question. The specification is clear in regards to using witness to initializing a variable with a default value. The standalone compilation doesn't complain while the VSC complains about n being uninitialized. As for the assertion it seems that witness is not effective in ghost statements and Dafny specifications doesn't presume that.

Comment: Well, that's your interpretation. I'm not on the Dafny development team, but if you think it's a bug in Dafny 4.0 then you should post it as an issue on the Dafny github. https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/issues